# can i use my visa Schengen for my first trip to a different country other than it issued from?

Tags: visas, schengen

i have a Visa type C , Multiple Entry with 1 year of validity to the Netherlands(issuing Country),
so i want to visit first Spain for a week and then go to my destination which is the Netherlands.
can i do this without having any problem in my upcoming application ?

Comment: "my upcoming application": which application is that?  Do you mean your application for a new visa after this one expires?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean, my next application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Schengen visa, you can make minor adjustments to your itinerary.

You may not misrepresent your itinerary to get a visa, **and you should avoid giving the impression that you misrepresented your itinerary.**

So the question is if that week in Spain will be minor.

- Will you still be longer in the Netherlands than in Spain?
- Is the purpose for your stay in the Netherlands unchanged?
- Did you mention that you would transit through Spain?

Comment: 1 -yeah i'm planing to stay in the Netherlands for about 10 days, 2- yes 3 - the trip to the Netherlands has nothing to do with the one in spain , the issue that i'm concerned about is the fact that i want to go to spain first

Comment: @OmarEL, are you going directly from Spain to the Netherlands?

Comment: no, i'm going to go back home then after a week or so, i'm heading to the netherlands

Comment: @OmarEL, then that **will** probably be a problem. You would be going to Spain first with a visa from the Netherlands, and that looks as if your initial application misrepresented the travel plans. They might not even let you into Spain.